# Sub-set sum recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, subset-sum

I wrote this function but it only works on non-negative integers.

```
int is_sum(int x, int a[], int n)

    {
        if (x == 0)
            return 1;
        if (n==0)
            return 0;

        return is_sum(x-a[n-1], a, n-1) || is_sum(x, a, n-1);
    }
```

How can I make it work on negative integers and how can i jump in 2?

```
int is_sum(int x, int a[], int n)

    {
        if (x == 0)
            return 1;
        if (n==0)
            return 0;

        return is_sum(x-a[n-1], a, n-1) || is_sum(x, a, n-1);
    }
```

Comment: Please give sample input to demonstrate working and non-working inputs.

Comment: Wouldn't it be: return is_sum(x-a[n], a, n-2) || is_sum(x, a, n-1) bcoz no adjacent elements are allowed?

Comment: The show code works for non-negative numbers AND heeds the "no adjacant numbers" rule? I fail to see that in the code, for that I would expect `is_sum(x-a[n-1], a, n-2)` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
int isSubsetSum(int a[], int n, int sum)
{
   if (sum == 0)
     return 1;
   if (n <= 0)
     return 0;

   return isSubsetSum(a, n-1, sum) || 
                        isSubsetSum(a, n-2, sum-a[n-1]);
}
```

Comment: working!
THANK YOU SO MUCH! Greetings and blessing for you!

Comment: If the solution is working for you @sher , you can accept it. Welcome to stackoverflow!